# C# - Login Role (Permissions) revert to default user

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, initialization

I am trying to implement a login based on user in my library application.

I have done the below code so far, but something is missing / wrong.

Keep in mind that an admin should have all permissions in the app.

- I login as admin (admin username is 'jHarrington')
- Menu permissions show correctly
- Upon navigating through the sub-menus and reverting back to the main menu, it looks like I (admin user) lose permissions (specifically User Menu permission), i.e. I get the same permissions as a normal user (which has the username 'pDinklage'), where User Menu is disabled (grayed out)

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

PS. I know about the SQL Injection issue, I will sort that out.

Login Form:

```
 private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Database Connection Setup
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Library System Project.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
        string query = "Select User_Username from Users where User_Username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and User_Password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, Connection);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(DT);

        // Access to Main Menu for Authorized Users
        if (DT.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            MainMenuForm MainMenu = new MainMenuForm();
            MainMenu.SetRole(DT.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            MainMenu.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        // Show Message Box of incorrect credentials submitted
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login credentials. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

Main Menu Form:

```
public partial class MainMenuForm : Form
{
    public MainMenuForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetRole(string Role)
    {
        lblRole.Text = Role;
    }

    private void MainMenuForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Form)this).Controls["lblRole"].Text == "jHarrington")
        {
           btnUserMenu.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Anyone can help, please?

Comment: Can someone provide some feedback on this, please?